# iOS iPhone Core Data how to find an object within a to many relationship using a specific property?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, search, core-data

I got a core data entity named Application, and it can have multiple screenshots added to it as a set. Each screenshot has an "order" attribute, which I'm hoping to use to pull only the first screenshot out of each set.

Below is the code that I'm currently using, but **maybe there's something easier/more efficient that I can use to pull out a screenshot with a particular order from a -to many relationship?**

```
   if(managedObject.screenshots.count>0)
        {

            //search for a screenshot 
            NSMutableArray* predicatesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
            [predicatesArray addObject:
            [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.order == %d",0]];
            [predicatesArray addObject:
            [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.application == %@",managedObject]];

            NSPredicate* compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicatesArray];

            NSFetchRequest *firstScreenshot = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Screenshot"];
            firstScreenshot.predicate = compoundPredicate;

            NSError* error;
            NSArray* results =  [managedObject.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:firstScreenshot error:&error];

            if(error)
            {
                DLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            }

            //if we got a result
            if(results.count>0)
            {
                Screenshot* screenshot = [results objectAtIndex:0];
                cell.screenshot.image = [UIImage imageWithData:screenshot.image];
            }else
            {
              cell.screenshot.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank1.png"];  
            }

        }
```

Comment: Seems fine. You can use one `NSPredicate` like this:

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"application == %@ order == %d",managedObject, 0]];`

You can also get the minimum order attribute with `valueForKeyPath`: `NSInteger minumumOrder = [managedObject.screenshots valueForKeyPath:@"@min.order"];

Comment: I sugest to add a previewImagePath to your entity and avoid doing fetches in to the cell for row at index path. This will slow down your scroll performance. You want to scroll as fas as you can. So is good to have all loaded in memory when you enter the cellForRow.